# Is the Date Created file attribute in finder a reliable install history timestamp to reference?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

I'm looking at my MacOS `/Applications` folder and looking at the `Date Created` column and was surprised to find a date newer than the date of a `.band` file I created from GarageBand which is listed as 2/1/2024.

The Applications folder
[image: MacOS /Applications Folder]

A GarageBand Project file created before the app folder's creation date
[image: A GarageBand Project created earlier than the app folder's creation date]

Maybe some post install updates recreated the folder under /Applications? What's going on here? If I wanted to look up my install history where would I actually locate it?

Comment: cross referencing some very closely related posts looking at the timestamps in the /Applications folder: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440738/what-does-modified-date-of-application-means, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/456971/applications-all-have-same-date-modified-created-and-added, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214066/277307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creation dates of applications has, as you have discovered, been covered many times.  In general (but not always) Finder's creation date of an application is when created by the developer.

For installation history:

1. Option-click on the Apple at top left of screen, select System Information. Look in Software > Installations which gives a clear Install Date for many applications.
2. Finder shows Date Added which indicates when the app was added to the /Applications folder.